# Laravel : Resetting some value from `Input`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any way that I can reset some value from the `Input` on the server side. Let's say, I am getting the value in `foo` i.e. `Input::get('foo')` on the server side, but I don't want that in `Input`. How may I reset that?

Now all I can think of is getting `$formData = Input::except('foo')` to get all the input values except `foo` and the processing this `$formData` instead. But I don't want to change my whole implementation for that, so is there any otherway provided by Laravel?

Comment: I dont understand - you seem to have answered your own question - just use `Input::except()`?

Comment: I didn't want to change the implmentation, as `Input::get(..)` was being used every where, so.. Thanks though, I have found it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was as simple, as the following:

```
Input::merge(array('foo' => null));
```

Comment: It's not really a workaround as that's what this method is intended for.